# How can I loop through a data matrix and compute on select rows?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, matrix, bioinformatics

I have the following data matrix called matrix1:

```
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
A    1    1    4    1   19   15
C    2    1    1    1    1    1
G    1   19   15   19    1    4
T   18    1    2    1    1    2
```

For rows A and T, I would like all the values divided by 0.3. For rows C and G I would like all the values divided by 0.2. I would then like the new values returned in a matrix called matrix2.

Is there a way to loop through this matrix or use a conditional statement to have the proper rows get divided by the proper value? Please let me know!!

Comment: Please use `dput(matrix1)` to provide an easily source-able matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(1)
matrix1 <- matrix(rpois(24, lambda = 5), 4, 6)
rownames(matrix1) <- c("A", "C", "G", "T")
matrix1

#  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#A    4    3    6    6    6    9
#C    4    8    2    4   11    3
#G    5    9    3    7    4    6
#T    8    6    3    5    7    3


matrix2 <- matrix1 # make copy
ATs <- which(rownames(matrix1) %in% c("A", "T")) # index of A&T
CGs <- which(rownames(matrix1) %in% c("C", "G")) # index of C&G
matrix2[ATs,] <- matrix1[ATs,] / 0.3
matrix2[CGs,] <- matrix1[CGs,] / 0.2
matrix2

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]     [,4]     [,5] [,6]
#A 13.33333   10   20 20.00000 20.00000   30
#C 20.00000   40   10 20.00000 55.00000   15
#G 25.00000   45   15 35.00000 20.00000   30
#T 26.66667   20   10 16.66667 23.33333   10
```

Or, as a loop:

```
for(i in seq(nrow(matrix1))){
  if(rownames(matrix1)[i] %in% c("A", "T")){
    matrix2[i,] <- matrix1[i,] / 0.3
  } else {
    matrix2[i,] <- matrix1[i,] / 0.2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```
matrix1 / ifelse(rownames(matrix1) %in% c("A", "T"), 0.3, 0.2)
```

which gives

```
       [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
A  3.333333  3.333333 13.333333  3.333333 63.333333 50.000000
C 10.000000  5.000000  5.000000  5.000000  5.000000  5.000000
G  5.000000 95.000000 75.000000 95.000000  5.000000 20.000000
T 60.000000  3.333333  6.666667  3.333333  3.333333  6.666667
```

**Data**

```
> dput(matrix1)
structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 18L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 15L, 2L,
1L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Dim = c(4L,
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "C", "G", "T"), NULL))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also do

```
matrix1/c(0.2, 0.3)[1+(rownames(matrix1) %in% c("A", "T"))]
```

-output

```
  [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
A  3.333333  3.333333 13.333333  3.333333 63.333333 50.000000
C 10.000000  5.000000  5.000000  5.000000  5.000000  5.000000
G  5.000000 95.000000 75.000000 95.000000  5.000000 20.000000
T 60.000000  3.333333  6.666667  3.333333  3.333333  6.666667
```

#### data

```
matrix1 <- structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 18L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 15L, 2L,
1L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Dim = c(4L,
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "C", "G", "T"), NULL))
```